# Setting time ie. 2 weeks, 1 month, 1 year, etc

Tags: go

I'm refactoring a bunch of my existing Go code.  In a lot of places, I have used `86400 * { days }` for setting things like MaxAge, etc.

Is there a more intuitive way to set these?  I have a lot more use cases now where I need to use time validations and things, but I am wondering how to do something like time in 2 standard weeks, or time in 6 standard months, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [AddDate](https://godoc.org/time#Time.AddDate)

```
 twoWeeksFromNow := time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, 14)
 oneMonthFromNow := time.Now().AddDate(0, 1, 0)
 oneYearFromNow := time.Now().AddDate(1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Also, I figure I'd ask this too - any idea how to convert a time.duration to int?

Comment: Use a [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to convert a duration to an int: int(d)

Comment: ah i see.  Thank you!

Comment: Generally you should _not_ convert a duration to an `int`. A duration is an `int64`, converting to an `int` will almost always be meaningless. If what you want is the number of seconds, you should use `int(dur / time.Second)`. This is the [suggested approach](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration).

Answer (score 3):

This is what the [Duration](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) type is for, along with its predefined constants.

Although be aware that it doesn't always handle days gracefully, due to timezone and daylight savings time changes, etc.  If you're okay with that, do something like:

```
maxAge := days * 24 * time.Hour
```

To add this to the current time, you can use [Add](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Add):

```
deadline := time.Now().Add(maxAge)
```